# .flv player for mobile browser

Tags: html, video

In my website there is video uploading facility. When User uploads video , My code convert the video format from (mp4,wmv,3gp,avi) to .flv format after compressing video size.

on desktop format, everything is working fine. But on mobile browser I haven't get an good player for playing .flv files in all browsers. Can somebody will help me to find a free .flv player support all mobile browser. I hjave searched on google and doesn't find any thing useful . I have tried with html5 player, but it doesn't work for .flv files. I also tried with  object player, which is not running in mobile browser.

Another one thing, downloadig .flv video wll be played in mobile or not?

Answer (score 3):

A mobile device will want to play an MP4 file. It won't know how to play a FLV file (unless the FLV file is really an MP4 file in disguise, which happens sometimes). The solution is for your website to transcode to MP4, not to FLV. If you have a desktop website solution that already plays FLV files, it's probably Flash-based, and it should be able to play MP4 files just as well.

Comment: But at the time of uploading video , my code compress the video and convert it to .flv file , that's why I am looking to play this compressed file in desktop and in mobile.